# Происходит ли подключение к индикаторам (7ми-сегментным)

Tags: таймер, vhdl

Вот код таймера от преподавателя где прописаны единицы и десятки секунд:

```
-- project Timer: template

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

use work.Math_PACK.all;

entity Timer is
    port 
    (
        -- module signals
        clk_i   : in std_logic;
        SS_Pin  : out SS_array(3 downto 0);
        
        
        -- simulation signals
        Ref_Freq_vp         : out std_logic;
        cnt_sec_10_carry_vp : out std_logic;
        cnt_sec_60_carry_vp : out std_logic;
        
        CLK50_vp            : out std_logic;
        
        cnt_sec_10_o_vp     : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        cnt_sec_60_o_vp     : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of Timer is

    CONSTANT Input_Freq      : natural := 50000000;                 -- input frequency value
    CONSTANT PRESCALER_RATIO : natural := Input_Freq / 10000000;    -- sets the counter switching step
    CONSTANT PRESCALER_SIZE  : natural := f_log2(PRESCALER_RATIO);  -- counter size


    signal prescaler_s  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(PRESCALER_SIZE-1 DOWNTO 0);
    signal pre_rst_s    : std_logic := '0';
    signal Ref_Freq_s   : std_logic := '0';
    
    
    signal cnt_sec_10_s         : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    signal cnt_sec_10_carry_s   : std_logic;
    
    signal cnt_sec_6x10_s       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    signal cnt_sec_6x10_carry_s : std_logic;

    COMPONENT Seven_Segment -- seven-segment indicator
        PORT
        (
            clock       :    IN STD_LOGIC;
            enable      :    IN STD_LOGIC;
            Number      :    IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
            Segment     :    OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;
    
    type Number_array is array(natural range <>) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    signal Number_s  :   Number_array(3 DOWNTO 0); -- counter code register
    signal Segment_s :   SS_array(3 downto 0);     -- decrypt code for seven-segment indicator
    
    component Main_PLL -- PLL
        PORT
        (
            inclk0      : IN STD_LOGIC  := '0';
            c0          : OUT STD_LOGIC 
        );
    end component;
    signal CLK50_s  :    STD_LOGIC; -- internal clock 

begin

------------------------------------- PLL -----------------------------------
    PLL: Main_PLL
        port map(
                    inclk0  => clk_i,
                    c0      => CLK50_s
                );

----------------------------------- PRESCALER -------------------------------
    Prescaler : process (CLK50_s) 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(CLK50_s)) then 
            prescaler_s  <= prescaler_s + '1';
            pre_rst_s <= '0';
            if (prescaler_s = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(PRESCALER_RATIO-1, PRESCALER_SIZE))) then
                prescaler_s <= (others => '0');
                pre_rst_s <= '1';
            end if;
            
        end if;
    end process;
    
    Ref_Freq_s <= pre_rst_s;
    
-------------------------------- second counter --------------------------------------
    cnt_1sec : process (CLK50_s) 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(CLK50_s)) then     
            -- counter up to 10
            -- counter states change on CLK50_s edge with the Ref_Freq_s frequency
            if (Ref_Freq_s = '1') then
                    cnt_sec_10_s <= cnt_sec_10_s + '1';
                    if (cnt_sec_10_s = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(9, 4))) then
                        cnt_sec_10_s <= (others => '0');
                    end if;
                    cnt_sec_10_carry_s <= '0';
                    if (cnt_sec_10_s = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(8, 4))) then
                        cnt_sec_10_carry_s <= '1';
                    end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
----------------------------- ten second counter ------------------------------------
    cnt_10sec : process (CLK50_s)
    begin   
        if (rising_edge(CLK50_s)) then
            -- counter up to 6 (from 0 to 5). Increases every 10 values (use cnt_sec_10_carry_s signal for this)
            if (Ref_Freq_s = '1' and cnt_sec_10_carry_s = '1') then
                cnt_sec_6x10_s <= cnt_sec_6x10_s + '1';
                if (cnt_sec_6x10_s = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5, 4))) then
                    cnt_sec_6x10_s <= (others => '0');
                end if;
                cnt_sec_6x10_carry_s <= '0';
                if (cnt_sec_6x10_s = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(4, 4))) then
                    cnt_sec_6x10_carry_s <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
            
----------------------------- seven-segment indicator --------------------------------  
    -- decrypt code from the counter into signals for seven-segment indicator
    process (CLK50_s) 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(CLK50_s)) then 
            Number_s(0) <= cnt_sec_10_s;
            Number_s(1) <= cnt_sec_6x10_s;
            Number_s(2) <= b"0011";
            Number_s(3) <= b"0100";
        end if;
    end process;

    Indicator: For I in 0 to 3 generate
        SS_Display: Seven_Segment
            port map(
                clock   => CLK50_s,
                enable  => '1',
                Number  => Number_s(I),
                Segment => Segment_s(I)
                    );
                    
        SS_Pin(I) <= Segment_s(I);
    End generate;
    
----------------------------- simulation signals --------------------------------       
    CLK50_vp <= CLK50_s;
    Ref_Freq_vp <= Ref_Freq_s;
    cnt_sec_10_carry_vp <= cnt_sec_10_carry_s;
    cnt_sec_60_carry_vp <= cnt_sec_6x10_carry_s;
    
    cnt_sec_10_o_vp <= cnt_sec_10_s;
    cnt_sec_60_o_vp <= cnt_sec_6x10_s;


end rtl;
```

И меня интересует конкретно этот момент:

```
----------------------------- seven-segment indicator --------------------------------  
    -- decrypt code from the counter into signals for seven-segment indicator
    process (CLK50_s) 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(CLK50_s)) then 
            Number_s(0) <= cnt_sec_10_s;
            Number_s(1) <= cnt_sec_6x10_s;
            Number_s(2) <= b"0011";
            Number_s(3) <= b"0100";
        end if;
    end process;

    Indicator: For I in 0 to 3 generate
        SS_Display: Seven_Segment
            port map(
                clock   => CLK50_s,
                enable  => '1',
                Number  => Number_s(I),
                Segment => Segment_s(I)
                    );
                    
        SS_Pin(I) <= Segment_s(I);
    End generate;
```

Вопрос такой, происходит ли здесь конкретное подключение индикаторов 7-сегментных ?

Эта прога от препода и она вроде как работает

[image: Нижние 2 сигнала, там идет счет единиц и десятков секунд]

Но я не пойму, есть ли тут подключение к индикаторам ?